# What happens when use a function with an argument by reference with a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

References with functions are rather confusing. You can put one in as an argument in a function definition, then put a non-reference non-pointer value in for the argument when you use it later. And then I thought about this:

```
int foo (int& bar)
{
    //Code
}

//More code...

int* a = &b;
c = foo (a);
```

What happens? Does foo use a, b, or what? How do I force either use?

Comment: That shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just test it yourself? Whenever you're in doubt, try compiling it!

**It won't work** and it makes sense - `foo()` is asking for a parameter of type `int&` - reference to an `int`, but you are trying to pass a pointer to it. The error you would get is something like

`cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'int &'`

Regarding your question

> How do I force either use?

Your function will currently be able to modify any `int` value passed to it, because it accepts a `reference` as a parameter.

If you **don't** want your function to be able to modify its argument, change its signature to:

`int foo (int bar)`

OR change the parameter to a reference to `const` `int`:

`int foo (const int& bar)`

Comment: It is worth mentioning another way to prevent modification of a function parameter is with const. int foo (const int & bar)

Answer (score 0):

> How do I force either use?

No it will generate compilation error. If want to understand diffence between references and pointers, please go through [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cuoqUkSjsc&list=PLkes6AxGmNZ7AuvPXe9WfwKNIzNPVEg-D&index=5) link.